# Successive appendReplacement calls fail

Tags: java, regex

3 groups in the regular expression:

pattern = (a)(b)123(c)

I need to get rid of a,b,c

in Java:

```
while (matcher.find()) {
  matcher.appendReplacement(sb, "");
  matcher.appendReplacement(sb, ""); // fails from here
  matcher.appendReplacement(sb, "");
}
```

exception:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -30
    at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.subSequence(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.getSubSequence(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Unknown Source)
```

Is there a way to successively replace the matched groups?

EDIT: sb is a `StringBuffer`. Both empty `new StringBuffer()` and non-emtpy `new StringBuffer(target_text_str)` have been tried.

java 1.6.0_21-b07

Comment: @Oltarus: it's probably a `StringBuffer`.

Comment: @Oltarus: ab"term1", term2, term3c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have only one `appendReplacement()` call per `find()` call:

```
while (matcher.find()) {
  matcher.appendReplacement(sb, "");
}
```

This would remove each *entire* match in your input.

If, as you indicated, you want to remove *some* parts of the match, then you must group *the part that you want to keep* and add that to the replacement. Using the pattern `ab(123)c` you'd do this:

```
while (matcher.find()) {
  matcher.appendReplacement(sb, "$1");
}
```

If you need the other groups for some other reasons (for example you need to evaluate them), then you can keep them (i.e. use `(a)(b)(123)(c)` and reference the third group using `$3` instead of `$1`).

Answer (score 2):

```
pattern = "(a)(b)(123)(c)"

// ...

while (matcher.find()) {
  matcher.appendReplacement(sb, "$3");
}
```

See [the docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement%28java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: why this will replace $1 and $2?

Comment: @D_K, it replaces the whole match with the part that you want to keep, thus removing the parts you don't want.

Comment: this is good, missed the (123) part. Great! Both yours and Joachim Sauer's qualify for the answer. stackoverlow does not allow me to mark both as answers to the question.